# How to access variable from a different class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to access a variable that is in the `WordSelect` class, then i'm trying to use it in the `Game`class. The code is as follows:
The WordSelect Class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordSelect {

    public WordSelect(){

    }

    public void Start(int diff){
        String words[] = new String[26];
        switch(diff){
        case 1:
            words[0] = "cat";
            words[1] = "dog";
            words[2] = "book";          
            words[3] = "breakfeast";          
            words[4] = "telephone";          
            words[5] = "mixture";          
            words[6] = "music";          
            words[7] = "animal";          
            words[8] = "school";          
            words[9] = "plant";          
            words[10] = "pen";          
            words[11] = "pencil";          
            words[12] = "paper";          
            words[13] = "note";          
            words[14] = "fog";          
            words[15] = "smoke";        
            words[16] = "bake";          
            words[17] = "alone";          
            words[18] = "drive";          
            words[19] = "town";          
            words[20] = "city";          
            words[21] = "sunny";          
            words[22] = "shine";          
            words[23] = "polish";          
            words[24] = "cap";          
            words[25] = "hat";
            break;

        case 2:
            words[0] = "president";
            words[1] = "exclamation";          
            words[2] = "statement";          
            words[3] = "television";          
            words[4] = "physics";          
            words[5] = "algebra";          
            words[6] = "geometry";          
            words[7] = "difficult";          
            words[8] = "extreme";          
            words[9] = "procedure";          
            words[10] = "ship";          
            words[11] = "soldier";          
            words[12] = "lunch";          
            words[13] = "hockey";          
            words[14] = "tennis";          
            words[15] = "soccer";          
            words[16] = "football";          
            words[17] = "basketball";          
            words[18] = "bias";          
            words[19] = "magazine";          
            words[20] = "computer";          
            words[21] = "internet";          
            words[22] = "allegedly";          
            words[23] = "system";          
            words[24] = "unison";          
            words[25] = "excited";         
            break;

        case 3:
            words[0] = "amalgamation";          
            words[1] = "proclomation";          
            words[2] = "establishment";          
            words[3] = "rehabilitation";          
            words[4] = "rhinoceros";          
            words[5] = "velociraptor";         
            words[6] = "declaration";         
            words[7] = "announcement";          
            words[8] = "binomial";          
            words[9] = "polynomial";          
            words[10] = "congregation";          
            words[11] = "obligation";          
            words[12] = "structure";          
            words[13] = "description";          
            words[14] = "perscription";          
            words[15] = "subscribe";          
            words[16] = "address";          
            words[17] = "township";          
            words[18] = "mischievous";          
            words[19] = "bewildered";          
            words[20] = "accusation";          
            words[21] = "designation";          
            words[22] = "disgusting";          
            words[23] = "prolonged";          
            words[24] = "restoration";          
            words[25] = "regeneration";          
        }

        int i = words.length;

        Random rng = new Random();
        int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word
        String wd = words[choice];
        // Not sure what to put here to make wd available in the other class
     }
}
```

And the Game Class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

    public static void game(){
        out.println(wd); //Trying to print out the wd variable from WordSelect

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, please see my answer. There I'm explaining you how can you accomplish that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the variable to be `static variable`, because in you case, I think that the `wd` variable is not related to any objects in your Class. So, the `static variable` must fit your need. Then, you just use it in the form of `Classname.variable`.

In the `WordSelect` class :

```
public class WordSelect {
public static String wd = words[choice];
public WordSelect(){
    ....
    ....
}

public void Start(int diff){
    ....
    ....
}
```

Then, in the `GameCalss` :

```
public class Game {

public static void game(){
    system.out.println(WordSelect.wd);  

}
}
```

**NOTE:** The `static variable` should be defined outside any methods.

Comment: Where would the public static String wd = words[choice]; be? Because if i am just adding public static to the beginning of where i had it at the bottom of the class, it is underlined in red. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @RyanHosford I have modified my answer. The most important thing is the `static variable` must be declared outside any methods - outside `Start method`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I'm sorry, but one last thing. My main class asks which difficulty of words you want to use (I'm making a hang man game) and the difficulties are sorted by case number by using an IF statement. Is there any way to, at the end of the `WordSelect` class, to make it run the `Game` class? because at the moment, after it chooses a word from the `WordSelect`, it ends the program. Thanks again, and i hope to soon get everything sorted out!

Comment: This is the worst way to achieve this. If you're trying to learn Java then you should be attempting an OO design. This answer is not OO. If this is a homework piece I wouldn't expect a good grade. ;)

Comment: @BenThurley No it's not homework. Just me messing around trying to make a hangman game.

Comment: @BenThurley Also, one more thing. What is an OO design? We haven't been taught that term in class yet.

Comment: OO = Object oriented. Before this there were procedural languages like C. Some languages like PHP started procedural but later had OO added. Java was designed from the start to be a pure OO language. Unfortunately it does still have a few less OO features such as the static keyword. As a learner you should look to avoid static until you understand objects and when static is appropriate. Your course should cover this though so don't let it bog you down from finishing your game. You could re-write it later to see the benefits of OO. This would be a good learning experience.

Comment: @BenThurley you cannot say that this is the worst way to achieve this. Because it depends on what you need. In Java, normally, we try to write everything in the form of OOP. However, there are also some static variables.

Comment: @Holmes if "normally we try to write everything in the form of OOP" then why not on this occasion? The start method isn't static so you still have to create an instance of WordSelect. It would be better to use a method return type or a non-static class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is declare an ivar for your class. Here I'm calling it `wordSelection`.

Then in the constructor method you can assign an initial value (empty) to the ivar.

Also, you have to add what's know as an "accessor method" to be able to read the ivar. Here I'm calling it `getWordSelection`.

In your `Game` class you will need an `instance` of the `WordSelection` class. You can accomplish that by using the `new` keyword. Please see the code for an example.

Finally, I don't see a `main` method anywhere in your code. You will need one to be able to run and test your program.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordSelect {

    // Add a priate ivar here...
    private String wordSelection;

    public WordSelect(){
        // give the ivar an initial value
        this.wordSelection = "";
    }

    // Add the method to access the ivar...
    public String getWordSelection() 
    {
        // this will return your saved word
        return wordSelection;
    }

    public void Start(int diff){
        String words[] = new String[26];
        switch(diff){
            // Your switch code here
            // I removed the switch code to keep the answer short
        }

        int i = words.length;

        Random rng = new Random();
        int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word

        // This is what you have to do
        wordSelection = words[choice];
     }
}
```

And the Game Class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

    public static void game(){

        // This is how you instantiate your WordSelect class
        WordSelect wordSelect = new WordSelect();

        // call the "Start" method
        wordSelect.Start(30);

        // This is how you can access the ivar
        out.println(wordSelect.getWordSelection()); 

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a few things. First, you need to create a variable to hold the String in your WordSelect class as follows:

```
String wd;
```

next you need a return method that returns a string:

```
public String returnWord()
{
     return wd;
}
```

Now we need to do a few things in your main. First we need to create a WordSelect object, then we need to call the Start method then we need to call the returnWord method and assign it to a string.

```
WordSelect words = new WordSelect();

words.Start(1);

String str = words.returnWord();

System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordSelect {
public WordSelect(){

}

private String wd = "";

public void Start(int diff){
    String words[] = new String[26];
    switch(diff){
    case 1:
      words[0] = "cat";
      words[1] = "dog";
      words[2] = "book";          
      words[3] = "breakfeast";          
      words[4] = "telephone";          
      words[5] = "mixture";          
      words[6] = "music";          
      words[7] = "animal";          
      words[8] = "school";          
      words[9] = "plant";          
      words[10] = "pen";          
      words[11] = "pencil";          
      words[12] = "paper";          
      words[13] = "note";          
      words[14] = "fog";          
      words[15] = "smoke";        
      words[16] = "bake";          
      words[17] = "alone";          
      words[18] = "drive";          
      words[19] = "town";          
      words[20] = "city";          
      words[21] = "sunny";          
      words[22] = "shine";          
      words[23] = "polish";          
      words[24] = "cap";          
      words[25] = "hat";

      break;
    case 2:
      words[0] = "president";
      words[1] = "exclamation";          
      words[2] = "statement";          
      words[3] = "television";          
      words[4] = "physics";          
      words[5] = "algebra";          
      words[6] = "geometry";          
      words[7] = "difficult";          
      words[8] = "extreme";          
      words[9] = "procedure";          
      words[10] = "ship";          
      words[11] = "soldier";          
      words[12] = "lunch";          
      words[13] = "hockey";          
      words[14] = "tennis";          
      words[15] = "soccer";          
      words[16] = "football";          
      words[17] = "basketball";          
      words[18] = "bias";          
      words[19] = "magazine";          
      words[20] = "computer";          
      words[21] = "internet";          
      words[22] = "allegedly";          
      words[23] = "system";          
      words[24] = "unison";          
      words[25] = "excited";         
      break;
    case 3:
      words[0] = "amalgamation";          
      words[1] = "proclomation";          
      words[2] = "establishment";          
      words[3] = "rehabilitation";          
      words[4] = "rhinoceros";          
      words[5] = "velociraptor";         
      words[6] = "declaration";         
      words[7] = "announcement";          
      words[8] = "binomial";          
      words[9] = "polynomial";          
      words[10] = "congregation";          
      words[11] = "obligation";          
      words[12] = "structure";          
      words[13] = "description";          
      words[14] = "perscription";          
      words[15] = "subscribe";          
      words[16] = "address";          
      words[17] = "township";          
      words[18] = "mischievous";          
      words[19] = "bewildered";          
      words[20] = "accusation";          
      words[21] = "designation";          
      words[22] = "disgusting";          
      words[23] = "prolonged";          
      words[24] = "restoration";          
      words[25] = "regeneration";          
  }

int i = words.length;

Random rng = new Random();
int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word
this.wd = words[choice];

}

//// setter and getter of wd;

public void setWd(String wd) {
this.wd = wd;
}

public String setWd() {
return this.wd;
}

}
```

Game.java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Game {

public static void game(){

    WordSelect ws = new WordSelect();
    out.println(ws.getWd());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about this.

1 You could change the start method to return a String.

```
public String start(int diff){
...
String wd = words[choice];
return wd;
}
```

Then

```
WordSelect ws = new WordSelect();
out.println(ws.start());
```

note I changed the Start method to start, methods should start lowercase.

2 You could save this as a class attribute in WordSelect

```
public class WordSelect {
private String word;
...
public String start(int diff){
...
String wd = words[choice];
word = wd;
}
...
public String getWord(){
return word;
}
}
```

Then

```
WordSelect ws = new WordSelect();
ws.start();
out.println(ws.getWord());
```

3 You could also try saving the attribute as a public attribute and not having a getter. This is not recommended though as you're losing one of the best features of OO, encapsulation.

4 You could also save it as a static variable as mentioned but these should be kept to a minimum. Static variables have their place, such as constants, but they're not really the OO way. Remember a static variable will apply to all objects of the same class. One of the main benefits of OO is that you can have different objects from the same class, each with different "state".

I think I would have designed these classes a bit differently. Why initialize the array every time you want to get a random word? It might be better doing this sort of thing elsewhere, maybe in a constructor, then having a single method to get a random word. Keep the array private to that class so that it's encapsulated. That way you can easily change it in future to use an ArrayList or whatever.